# I am trying to compile in xcode an open source game called supertux but I keep getting file not found errors

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation

The src file is broken down into different libraries and inside each one is the xxx.c and its xxx.h counterpart.  In almost all of my classes I get file not found errors on the first import statement for the .h file. I deleted the "library/" and it removes the error. I was wondering if there is an easier way to to this other than going through each of the 1000 classes and doing this for each of the import statements. I have already included sdl framework in the "Link binaries with Libraries". Please help im lost.

[image: before the deletion]
[image: after the deletion]

[image: this is the inside of the src folder]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for paths you want searched for `#include "..."` You can find this option in Build Settings of Target.

You can specify path like this: `$(SRCROOT)/Subfolder/subfolder`